# Use wp.media templates to create totally custom modal

Tags: media-modal

Following up on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85442/is-it-possible-to-reuse-wp-media-editor-modal-for-dialogs-other-than-media/98907#98907) I'm trying to determine how to create a modal with completely unique menu items/content than the media modal.

If you add a new `state` you can add a new menu tab and have it render the appropriate content when clicked. However, what I've found so far is that if you don't include the traditonal `wp.media.controller.Library()` states (for gallery, insert, etc) then the menu does not render at all and you are left with an empty media frame.

I've started a [gist](https://gist.github.com/helgatheviking/646566f654c58335ab7471c0173cd4a8) for a plugin, and the modal opens, but so far there's nothing in it.

Does anyone know how to create custom frames with custom states?

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I think [Extending the WordPress Media Uploader: Embed Options](https://www.ibenic.com/extending-wordpress-media-uploader-embed-options/) should work. I'm trying to do the same.